# Robot movement measuring using matlab video processing

Tags: matlab, image-processing, robotics, measurement

I'm doing robot project - It need to measure subtle movements in XY direction, while driving in Z direction .
So I was thinking of using a camera with MATLAB and blinking LED attached to a wall - that way using image subtraction I can identify the LED, and with weight matrix locate the center of the light.
Now every period of time I can log the amount of pixels the center moved right-left or up-down directions and check the accuracy of the motion.

But when attempting this sensing solution I had some challenges I couldn't overcome

- light source like LED/laser has soft edges so the center is not accurate
- the camera is not calibrated (and I'm not sure how to calibrate it)

Is there other simple solution for this problem?

note: the amount of motion can be proportional.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to improve the accuracy of the location of the led by applying some kind of peak interpolation.

For the calibration: Matlab offers an app for camera calibration, maybe that helps you.